# How to create .ipa file & how to install .ipa in iphone/ipad?

Tags: iphone

I have developed a mobile native app using jquerymobile.

Now I want to deploy that app on `iPhone`.

For this one I want **.ipa** file. How to create `.ipa` & install **.ipa** file in the `iPhone`?

Comment: Sounds like you've made an html5 app, not a native app, are you using Xcode at all?

Answer (score 1):

To complete this you will need to do the following:

- In `Xcode`, Go To `Product -> Archive` (this will build the app)
- after the build is complete the `Organizer - Archives` window will show (this lists all of your archived versions of the app)
- at the top left above the list there will be a `Distribute` button, click it
- this will bring up a 'wizard' for creating the **.ipa** file
- Select the `Save for Enterprise or Ad-Hoc Deployment` option
- click next
- you will now need to select a `Code Signing Identity` (this is created in the Provisioning area of the apple developer portal
- if you do not have a Development or Distribution cert to create one go to https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/provisioningprofiles/index.action and create one for the app you plan to create the ipa file for
- **note:** *you will need to have the cert installed on your keychain before it will become an option, as well if you are in the process of
  creating the file you may need to restart after installing the cert
  to the keychain*
- select the cert that you created for Development/Distribution
- click next
- this will take a few moments so be patient, once complete it will ask what you would like to name the new file
- enter the name of your new ipa file and this will be what you will need to send out or make available to your users

After that for your users who need to install the ipa on their devices you can check out http://www.itexico.com/blog/bid/41187/iPhone-or-iPad-Testing-Installing-applications-with-a-ipa-file

**note:** my users have not been required to use the `.mobileprovision` file, but that has been my experience

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In `Xcode`, Go To `Product -> Archive` then after build archived it will show a screen there will a option like `Share`. Once you will click you will get the other options in which one of them is **.ipa**. Select and build it. For installing you need to add via through iTunes.

Comment: how can i install Xcode in mac system? is there any link to install? how can i do that?

Comment: Kalyan, I think you're a bit confused, if you're not already using Xcode you can't create an .ipa

Answer (score 0):

Look into [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/) that probably does what you need